# Compiler bug with overloaded function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, overload-resolution

The following code gives a stack overflow:

```
function Func(x : Double) : Double; overload;
function Func(x : Integer) : Double; overload;


function Func(x : Double) : Double;
begin
  Result := Func(Round(x));
end;


function Func(x : Integer) : Double;
begin
  Result := 1.0;
end;
```

The `Integer` overloaded function is never called, the `Double` overloaded function calls itself until the stack overflows.

The following code works as expected:

```
function Func2(x : Double) : Double; overload;
function Func2(x : Integer) : Double; overload;

function Func2(x : Double) : Double;
var
  ix : Integer;
begin
  ix := Round(x);
  Result := Func(ix);
end;


function Func2(x : Integer) : Double;
begin
  Result := 1.0;
end;
```

Is this a compiler bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, I suspect, to be expected.

The issue is that the compiler-intrinsic `Round` function returns a 64-bit integer. Both CodeInsight and [the official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Round) tells me that. And if the compiler has to chose between a routine taking a 32-bit integer or a double, when given a 64-bit integer, it chooses the routine accepting a double.

To verify this, try

```
procedure Test(x: Double); overload;
begin
  ShowMessage('double');
end;

procedure Test(x: Integer); overload;
begin
  ShowMessage('integer');
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test(Int64.MaxValue)
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

[System.Round](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Round.html) function results an `Int64` value.

I think that the compiler retains that the `Double` overload of your `Func` function is more appropriated than the `Integer` overload.

In fact, the `Integer` overload could cause information loss if the param's value exceeds the `Integer`'s type min-max (from -2147483648 to 2147483647, see [System.Integer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Integer)).

Changing the `Integer` param to an `Int64` param will solve the problem and avoid information losses.

```
function Func(x : Double) : Double; overload;
function Func(x : Int64) : Double; overload;

...

function Func(x : Double) : Double;
begin
  Result := Func(Round(x));
end;

function Func(x : Int64) : Double;
begin
  Result := 1.0;
end;
```